# Comparison two files

Tags: shell

Can anyone create a shell script that would compare two files and return discrepancies from both the files.

One file is having five paragraphs and another file is having three paragraphs common from first file. But the comparison has to happen with appropriate paragraph.

I have tried with `diff -y file1 file2 | grep "|"` to identify discrepancies, but the result is inconsistent (line to line comparison but inconsistent comparison because of missing line in between).

Comment: Code please. So we can know what's the problem causing it. The way you structure your question, the answer people can only give to you is: Yes, it is possible to create a shell script that would compare two files and return discrepancies from both the files

Comment: diff -y source.txt target.txt | grep "[<|>]" | awk -F"[<|>]" '{ if( $1 ~ /^Comparing/ ) { print $1 $2} else { print "Expected value is:"$1 "Actual value is:" $2}}' >> Discrepancies.txt

Comment: I have tried the above script to compare,but I have to compare appropriate paragraphs.My script is comparing line to line from two files which compares one line in file1 to another line of some other paragraph due to missing paragraphs in between.

Answer (score 0):

```
diff -y file1 file2 | grep ' [|<>] '
```